# A problem with IBM Q, NameError: name 'iBMQ' is not defined

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I 'm trying to reproduce the code given in the Qiskit summer school [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJX794qJIpY).

The code is:

```
# initialization

import numpy as np

# import Qiskit

from qiskit import IBMQ, BasicAer
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
 provider= iBMQ.load.account()
```

but I am getting this error:

```
 NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-9-5e15427b4944> in <module>
  9 from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
  10 from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
  ---> 11 provider= iBMQ.load.account()
  12 
  13 #import basic plot tools

  NameError: name 'iBMQ' is not defined
```

The same question was asked so I tried the answer to install IBM Q provider using the command

```
  pip install qiskit-ibmq-provider
```

but still I am getting the same error.

My python version is 3.8.3 and qiskit version is '0.16.0'

```
   {'qiskit-terra': '0.16.0',
   'qiskit-aer': '0.7.0',
   'qiskit-ignis': '0.5.0',
   'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.11.0',
   'qiskit-aqua': '0.8.0',
   'qiskit': '0.23.0'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is you have:

`provider= iBMQ.load.account()` **instead of** `provider= IBMQ.load_account()` on **line 11** of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. typoo... I m getting this error now: 
AttributeError: 'IBMQFactory' object has no attribute 'load' though

Comment: Try: `provider= IBMQ.load_account()`

Comment: Thank you so much, :). it works